# Effect of heap allocation vs lack of heap allocation in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, observer-pattern

> I've managed to write a program that implements the Game of Life using the Observer design pattern, but it seems that one of my functions, Grid::init() only works if I allocate the Cells on the heap and doesn't work otherwise. Below is the class definition for a Grid.

```
// Grid class
// Grid is initially empty. Sets up a TextDisplay observer when init() is called
// and the grid is initialized with cell objects.
class Grid {
    TextDisplay *td = nullptr;         
    std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> cells; 
    size_t size; 
 
  public:
    ~Grid(); 
    void setObserver(Observer *ob); 
  
    void init( size_t n );              
    void turnOn( size_t r, size_t c );  
    void tick();                        
    
    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, const Grid & g );
};
```

A Cell is a unit of the grid, and stores info such as its position and state. I tried to initialize the grid by indirectly allocating the Cells on the heap through vector, but that didn't work; instead, when I changed
the cells element of the grid class to be an

std::vector<std::vector<Cell *>> the implementation worked.

Comment: Could we see the non-functional code in a [mre] instead? Odds are something you didn't want copied got copied and broke the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: In the stack version, after attaching the observer, did you still add cells to the grid? Adding elements to a vector can cause the vector to be relocated, invalidating all pointers to elements in that vector.

Comment: Run your program under the address sanitizer. The address sanitizer is probably the coolest, most amazing, best tool for C++ programmers ever made in the history of C++. That, and delete the copy constructor / copy assignment operator on classes that shouldn’t be copied (probably both `Grid` and `Cell` for starters, and maybe `Observer` as well). Once you do those two things, I can take another look at your code. Otherwise, the only general advice I have is that you probably have dangling pointers to `Cell`, and that pointers to elements in a `std::vector` change when the vector is copied.

Comment: To use the address sanitizer, compile and link with `-fsanitize=address` if you are using Clang or GCC. If you are not using Clang or GCC (if you are using MSVC), it is probably worthwhile to install either Clang or GCC just so you can use the address sanitizer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Comment: @DietrichEpp I cannot and should not modify the Observer class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I *might* know what is going on. There are several problems with this code, and I think I have figured out what combination of problems is causing the behavior.

**Problem #1:** Classes have unsafe copy constructors / copy assignment operators.

In general, any class which uses pointers should override the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor. The easy way to do this is to simply not use pointers, or just use smart pointers, but that isn’t a panacea.

In particular, `Grid` is unsafe to copy. Both the `std::vector<Cell *>` and `std::vector<Cell>` versions are unsafe… but for different reasons!

**Problem #2:** This curious pattern:

```
TextDisplay newDisplay(n);
td = new TextDisplay{newDisplay};
```

This constructs **two** `TextDisplay` objects. One is a copy of the other. Ordinarily, this might just be a roundabout or slow way of creating one object, but that’s only the case if the class doesn’t have problem #1 above.

### What is Causing the Problem

If you create a copy of `Grid` containing `std::vector<Cell>`, the addresses of all the cells will change! This does not apply to `Cell *`.

You should prevent this from happening by deleting the `Grid` copy constructor (and the copy assignment operator).

```
class Grid {
    Grid(const Grid &) = delete;
    Grid &operator=(const Grid &) = delete;
};
```

This may show you where the problem is.

### Get Rid of Bare Pointers

In general, modern C++ advice (since the 2011 edition) is to use smart pointers instead of bare pointers.

So, instead of `Cell *`, use `std::unique_ptr<Cell>` or `std::shared_ptr<Cell>`.

This doesn’t necessarily apply to “non-owned” pointers like the `std::vector<Observer *>` inside `Subject`, and it doesn’t work for interior pointers (like a pointer to a single cell in a `std::vector<Cell>`), but…

- You should probably use `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cell>>>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<Cell *>>`
- You should probably use `std::unique_ptr<TextDisplay>` instead of `TextDisplay *`.
- In general, if you can figure out a way to avoid calling `new`, avoid calling `new`.

### A Note About the Heap

Note that `std::vector<Cell>` and `std::vector<Cell *>` both allocate on the heap. It’s just that `std::vector<Cell *>` has an extra layer of indirection.

```
                           Heap
+-------------------+     +------+
| std::vector<Cell> | --> | Cell |
+-------------------+     +------+
                          |  ... |

                             Heap
+---------------------+     +--------+     +------+
| std::vector<Cell *> | --> | Cell * | --> | Cell |
+---------------------+     +--------+     +------+
                            |    ... |
```

Comment: Get Rid of Bare Pointers is the best advice, unfortunately pointers seem to be all some students are taught.

Comment: @Gord452: If deleting copy + copy assignment caused segmentation faults, then **there is a problem somewhere in your program.** Calling `cells.clear()` will destroy all objects in `cells` but will not free memory used by the vector. If the vector contains `Cell *`, then the `Cell` objects will not be freed.

Comment: @Gord452: If you have a segmentation fault and you don’t know where it is, try using the address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address` with GCC or Clang) or attaching a debugger. The address sanitizer is usually the fastest way to find what the problem is.

Comment: @Gord452: If you want to put the cells on the stack, you can’t use `std::vector` **at all** because `std::vector` uses the heap (unless you got some wacky allocator stuff going on). The easiest way to put cells on the stack is to use a fixed-size array, like `Cell cell[20][20];`. But remember, each cell has a `std::vector`, so it will still use the heap this way.

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks for your answer, though it seems I'm still experiencing issues. I've updated my question.